# How to position images according to background image and not window browser

Tags: css

I have asked this question before but no one seemed to get what i was saying since it was in writing so i have now made a 2:12 min. video where I illustrate my problem.

the link to the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7XfQS_-gp98&feature=youtu.be

The relavant css code for this problem:

```
#BackgroundImage{
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
hight: 100%;

}

#Frame{
position: absolute;
width: 34.68%;
height: auto;

}

#Logo{
position: absolute;
width: 19.32%;
top: 8.5%;
left: 5%;
height: auto;
}
```

I have made a fiddle aswell where you can find the relavant html code aswell in case any needs it.

https://jsfiddle.net/ff154bsa/

Thx in advance for any contribution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your top:8,5% refers to the height. What if you refer to the width? Try to refer the misure to the width in this way:

```
top:8vw;
```

Comment: I think it still for viewport width, so the misure used is a percentual based on the width of the viewport! Love you too lol